# Django user-profile creation code is running twice - why?

Tags: django

Using Django 1.2, I'm running the *django-registration* application, and creating a User Profile object after registration created the user - using code that came from some other Questions:

```
# models.py
def create_player_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    signals.post_save.disconnect(create_player_profile, sender = User) # added.
    if created:
        print "creating profile."
        profile, created = PlayerProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)
        print "profile %s created = %s" % (str(profile), str(created))
    else:
        print "problems creating profile."

signals.post_save.connect(create_player_profile, sender = User)
```

And it works fine :) The only problem is, I get two sets of output, indicating that the code is running *twice*. I suspect that for some reason, the signal is getting sent twice.

My first thought is that the file is getting *imported* twice, setting up two identical signals. Which makes me wonder if maybe *django-registration* is doing something automatically? Or something else I don't yet understand about Django. :)

So why is the code running twice? Are two signals being sent, and if so, why?

**Update** Just noticed [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478630/django-signal-emitting-once-received-twice-why/1480174#1480174) explained how to avoid duplicate signals. And it worked, somewhat :) My output went from:

> creating profile.
>   creating profile.
>   problems creating profile
>   problems creating profile

to:

> creating profile.
>   problems creating profile

I don't know if that means my code was originally running *four times*? And dropped down to only two times? I'm so confused. :)

Update 2 - added the *signals.disconnect* line. I figured deleting the signal would prevent the function from executing twice. Alas, I was wrong - *create-player-profile* is *still* running twice... I have no clue why it would, if the signal was immediately deleted.

Comment: Can you show how did you change your code after reading the answer explaining how to avoid duplicate signals? Btw, this is the [official link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) about that.

Comment: I did what both links suggested, adding *dispatch_uid = "foo"* to the signal-creation, I just didn't re-edit the code above. But the problem is solved (or non-problem, as the case may be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: removed this stuff about `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`

> So why is the code running twice? Are
>   two signals being sent, and if so,
>   why?

I guess the problem is not that the signal is called twice, but your `User.save()` method is called twice somewhere (and therefore the signal as well). Maybe you should check this one first.

Comment: Wups, bad timing :) I already removed the AUTH setting from my post, after reading the docs more closely. Sorry. :) Also, I'm not calling User.save() at all - I presume *django-registration* is.

Comment: Its ok, removed it from my post as well. :p 
And yes, most likely its called twice within `django-registration` then. It doesn;t look like this though. I can't really say right now where, since this would require some more debugging.

Another guess is that there is this django internal signal (on `post_save`) and the one from `django-registration` (`user_registered` in their `signals.py`) triggering the same. Though that would be odd. Maybe you try to use their signal and check if its still occuring twice?

Comment: I did try using *django-registration*'s *user_registered* signal, with no arguments (and no Sender) with a dummy function - and the function fired twice. :)

Comment: I think the answer is yes, *django-registration* is just calling User.save() multiple times. And after reading the signals documentation, it's obviously a **non-problem**. The signal has a *created* boolean for that very reason - so you can tell when the record is first created, versus re-saving the record. Guess I just over-reacted, thinking I put in a bug when installing the registration app. Wups... :)

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen if the module has bad indentation, if you might have mixed up space and tab indents in the create_player_profile function then also this can happen.